# Pytest "uses no argument" error, but everything looks right?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working on a decryption program for cryptoquote puzzles, and wanted to practice using Pytest, but I've run into a sticky bug.

Here's my code:

```
import pytest

from decryptoquote import decryptoquote


class TestIntegration(object):
    test_data = [
        (
            """ Long code string 1""",
            """ Long solution string 1"""
        ),
        (
            """ Long code string 2""",
            """ Long solution string 2"""
        ),
        (
            """ Long code string 3""",
            """ Long solution string 3"""
        ),
    ]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("coded_quote, plaintext", test_data)
    def test_is_correct(coded_quote, plaintext):
        result = decryptoquote.decryptQuote(coded_quote)
        assert result == plaintext
```

I'm getting the "function uses no argument 'coded_quote'" error, and can't see why. I've used the right variable names, and I've added them to the test function arguments (which I see is a common error). I've tried using self.test_data instead of test_data, putting test_data outside the test class, just using decryptQuote instead of the version that references the imported module, but nothing works.

If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: `test_is_correct` is a method of the `TestIntegration` class but it's missing the `self` parameter.

Comment: You forgot the `self` argument in test method signature.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something dumb. Thanks!